# asset pipeline not working on production, tried everythign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a rails 3.2 app on heroku. I have tried everything I can find to try to fix the fact that the javascripts are not loading in production mode. Everything works fine in dev though. Also, when deploying to heroku, the precompiling fails. However, when I look at the source code in prod, I can clearly see the javascripts file (/assets/application-32fdbd115c5d59c7be2876c103063600.js) loading and has content.

I have tried every setting I can think of and have read about. I am not quite sure what to do. Here's my setup currently in production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

and in environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
App::Application.initialize!
```

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails/all"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

and my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'thin'
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'haml'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

nothing I do seems to get it to work on production mode on my local machine or on heroku. however, it works just fine in development.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Heroku? `heroku restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this, although I don't know how good of a fix it is. Basically, the problem was that the compression of the .js files into application.js was causing issues. In production.rb I put this:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.debug = true
```

this fixed the issue. however, now instead of application.js, it lists all the asset files. i'm not sure if there are any long-term issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

On your production box have you tried: `RAILS_ENV rake assets:precompile`

Comment: yes, I tried that a few different times and ways...but no luck

Comment: Do you get an error message of any kind, or just a failure to serve the assets?

Comment: I don't see any error messages, but I get a response 402 on my local machine when trying to load assets. It's weird because I see the javascripts compressed into the application.js file in the source. On heroku, I do get an error that the precompile failed. Again, i see the assets though in the .js file. Very odd

Comment: I just figured something out... in production, if I do ?debug_assets=1 it fixes the issue. that means that the cause of the problems is the fact that everything is being put into the single application.js file. any idea how to fix that without turning off compress?